# In Typescript, how do I modify a property with the type of an array that I got from using a generic key?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to make a generic function that only works for properties in an object type that extends `string[]`. For example, the object type might be:

```js
type Thing = {
    a: Thing2[],
    b: Thing3[],
    c: number,
}
const thing2 = ['!', '@', '#'] as const;
type Thing2 = typeof thing2[number];
const thing3 = ['1', '2', '3'] as const;
type Thing3 = typeof thing3[number];
```

and the function would only accept the keys `a` and `b`.

With all the unrelated code removed, so far I have:

```js
type KeysMatching<T, V> = {[K in keyof T]-?: T[K] extends V ? K : never}[keyof T];

function append<O extends object, K extends KeysMatching<O, string[]>>(
    obj: O,
    key: K,
    item: O[K] extends (infer U)[] ? U : never
) {
    obj[key].push(item); // Property 'push' does not exist on type 'O[K]'
}
```

but TypeScript doesn't seem to recognize that `obj[key]` is of type `string[]`. I would also like to avoid using the `as` keyword if possible.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mqpddN) meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing

Comment: @jcalz I might be misinterpreting your answer, but I think `Record<K, I[]>` limits `obj` to objects with only `string[]` properties. Would it be possible to allow objects with other property types to be accepted as well? For example, in `Thing` there is a property with a type of `number` which would cause the append function to not allow any object with type `Thing` to be accepted.

Comment: Please [edit] to show a [mre] of what calls you need to support and which ones you want to reject (also, `T` for a key is unconventional compared to `K`; you might want to change that).  The `Record<K, I[]>` approach should not limit it, but I'm not sure if it works the way you want. Does something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mbaYoN) work better for you?

Comment: @jcalz The second one works for me. I'll keep in mind to use K instead of T for keys in the future.

Comment: I'll write up an answer with the second approach.  Do you mind if I [edit] your question to use `K` instead of `T` so it's less distracting?

Comment: You can edit it, I don't mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently no native `KeysMatching<T, V>` type operator in TypeScript where the compiler actually understands that `T[KeysMatching<T, V>]` is assignable to `V` for [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) `T` and `V`. You can implement your own version, as shown in the question code, but as you see it doesn't work as desired inside the generic function implementation.  There's an open feature request at [microsoft/TypeScript#48992](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/48992) to support this sort of thing, but for now it's not part of the language.

Until and unless that changes, we'll need to work around it.  One workaround is to change the direction of the [generic constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) so that the object type `O extends Record<K, string[]>` (using the [`Record<K, V>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type)) instead of, or in addition to the existing constraint where `K extends KeysMatching<O, string[]>`.  Those represent the same or similar things from different angles.  Here's what it looks like if you do both at the same time:

```
function append<
  O extends Record<K, string[]>, 
  K extends KeysMatching<O, string[]>
>(obj: O, key: K, item: O[K][number]) {
  obj[key].push(item); // okay
}
```

Now the compiler knows that `obj[key]` is assignable to `string[]` and thus accepts `item`.  We can also write the type of `item` more simply as `O[K][number]` instead of the [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html); now that the compiler knows `O[K]` is an array type, we can directly [index into it](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) with `number` to get the element type.

---

And let's make sure it still works as expected from the caller's side:

```
function foo(thing: Thing) {
  append(thing, "a", "!"); // okay
  append(thing, "b", "2"); // okay
  append(thing, "c", "3"); // error!
  // ---------> ~~~ 
  // Argument of type '"c"' is not assignable to parameter of 
  // type 'KeysMatching<Thing, string[]>'.
  append(thing, "b", "!"); // error
  // --------------> ~~~
  // Argument of type '"!"' is not assignable to parameter of 
  // type '"1" | "2" | "3"'.  
}
```

Looks good.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgFgSwHYHMoF4oG8BQUoCGAXLIqgEwDaAugDR5QBGJ8yKAzDffgMYlIBXALaMIAJ3oBfHDwD2SAM7AowMinIYolAOQBCbbSjaAAgaMBibdUIKocxcADcOUJFJsNmVxFkAzFWpUgiLi1M72SgFs7Jo6AIxm2uSJ7FY2dvJKzt7uqDFe4D7+qtGUwaJiYTguhVAA0hAgCgCyBMA8agA8MIYAagB8mlhadVDIUADWjX6w1AC0APwslHXWEAAewBBIACa2vVAL9VD8EABu4lCSlFMgMzBVOL4CSDzACPKEYJC7nQDyUA2W12tgAShA5GIdp06oYlGI2DR+oZRkDtnt6o0Wm0Omx-nDgAjUEj+gAKBiyRgAKxIf24k0aJFhDAQWyEtJW1DKwgq1BwAEpsBTqTdGtQAHRgAQKOCk1kQIT85zSJ4vN4fJBQXyyWSkkqoFhqQW4fAEb7ovVqQwAIgI1ptumtSqgAHoXVBZBMCCAGGafjtLWwbYx7VBreQnY5Xe7Pd7febdoHUDaeKHrexI9HAWIxLIxLoGG6oHMS6XS4MAH5VqCF90AQTEKGE22UMxy2mtqe0Y1sSFkygICgUCBQSAIjAANtBgLIoGACGICEIIFsxB7-LWVLVtA0mq12l1WMmoPDEdR+tpxfH-UmUMG047nUXxLmxJuyx+P5Wq5uG03l0grbFNu1qOt2CC9v2NjDqO45Tios7zouy6ruuNb4EW7bWnE1pQAAPmGEb4WGGaXvgOCSEAA)